# want to create a timestamp using GPS data with python3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, gps

python3 Newby here.  I am trying to create a variable that I can use to make a GPS timestamp from an adafruit GPS sensor.  I eventually want to store this in a db.  The mysql database has a timestamp feature when data is inserted into a table so I want to have that and the UTC time and date that comes from the GPS device be stored as well.

It seems I have something wrong and can not figure it out.  The code is hanging on this:

```
def gpstsRead():  
    gps_ts = '{}/{}/{} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mon,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mday,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_year,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_hour,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_min,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_sec,
        )
    return gps_ts
```

I am trying to put all of these into a timestamp like format.  The error is this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ek9/Sensors/GPS/gps-db-insert.py", line 57, in <module>
    gps_ts = gpstsRead()
  File "/home/pi/ek9/Sensors/GPS/gps-db-insert.py", line 20, in gpstsRead
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mon,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tm_mon'
```

I have made sure I use spaces instead of tabs as that has caused me grief in the past.  Beyond that I really don't know.  I have been putzing with this for hours to no avail.  Any ideas?  thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The error tells you that `gps.timestamp_utc` is `None`, so this seems not to be a formatting issue

Comment: so you think it's formatted correctly?  It seems that a lot of errors in python occur when other parts of your code aren't structured properly so it will hang on something that doesn't really address the underlying problem.  I can provide the whole code set if anyone thinks that will help.  Just let me know!

Comment: "*when other parts of your code aren't structured properly*" - I'd suggest you specify the variables that should be passed to the function, don't just take them from the outer namespace. While that works, it often makes code harder to read & debug (exactly the problem you describe). So the def would be `def gpstsRead(gps)` with `gps` being an object of some kind. Maybe you could add the context within you call the function?

Comment: Have you imported the adafruit_gps module, have you properly instantiated the class?  What does this instantiation look like either ```gps = adafruit_gps.GPS(uart, debug=False)  # Use UART/pyserial``` or ```gps = adafruit_gps.GPS_GtopI2C(i2c, debug=False)  # Use I2C interface```?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the input.  After reading these I decided to try it a little different.  Instead of defining a variable with "def" i just decided to eliminate the "def" and just create the variable itself.

Like this:

```
    # define values
    gps_ts = ('{}-{}-{} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_year,
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mon,
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mday,
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_hour,
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_min,
    gps.timestamp_utc.tm_sec,)
    )
```

And that seemed to work.  For anyone that is doing something similar I will include the complete code.  I also understand that like most languages, there is always more than one way to get the job done, some better than others, some not.  I am still learning.  If anyone cares to point out how I could accomplish the same task by doing something different or more efficient, please feel free to provide me the opportunity to learn.  thanks again!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymysql
import time
import board
from busio import I2C
import adafruit_gps

i2c = I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
gps = adafruit_gps.GPS_GtopI2C(i2c)  # Use I2C interface
gps.send_command(b"PMTK314,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0")
gps.send_command(b"PMTK220,1000")
last_print = time.monotonic()

# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "database", "password", "table")
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

while True:
    gps.update()
    current = time.monotonic()
    if current - last_print >= 1.0:  # update rate
        last_print = current
        if not gps.has_fix:
            # Try again if we don't have a fix yet.
            print("Waiting for a satellite fix...")
            continue
    # define values
        gps_ts = ('{}-{}-{} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_year,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mon,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_mday,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_hour,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_min,
        gps.timestamp_utc.tm_sec,)
        )

        gps_lat = '{}'.format(gps.latitude)

        gps_long = '{}'.format(gps.longitude)

        gps_fix = '{}'.format(gps.fix_quality)

        gps_sat = '{}'.format(gps.satellites)

        gps_alt = '{}'.format(gps.altitude_m)

        gps_speed = '{}'.format(gps.speed_knots)

        gps_track = '{}'.format(gps.track_angle_deg)

        sql = "INSERT into ek9_gps(gps_timestamp_utc, latitude, \
        longitude, fix_quality, number_satellites, gps_altitude, \
        gps_speed, gps_track_angle) \
        values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

        arg = (gps_ts, gps_lat, gps_long, gps_fix, gps_sat,
        gps_alt, gps_speed, gps_track)

        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            cursor.execute(sql, arg)
            # Commit your changes in the database
            db.commit()

        except:
            print('There was an error on input into the database')
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

And this is what the mariadb shows:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | datetime            | gps_timestamp_utc   | latitude | longitude | fix_quality | number_satellites | gps_altitude | gps_speed | gps_track_angle |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 11 | 2020-12-30 14:14:42 | 2020-12-30 20:14:42 |  xx.xxxx |  -xx.xxxx |           1 |                10 |          232 |         0 |             350 |
| 10 | 2020-12-30 14:14:41 | 2020-12-30 20:14:41 |  xx.xxxx |  -xx.xxxx |           1 |                10 |          232 |         0 |             350 |
|  9 | 2020-12-30 14:14:39 | 2020-12-30 20:14:39 |  xx.xxxx |  -xx.xxxx |           1 |                10 |          232 |         0 |             350 |
|  8 | 2020-12-30 14:14:38 | 2020-12-30 20:14:38 |  xx.xxxx |  -xx.xxxx |           1 |                10 |          232 |         0 |             350 |
```

Success!!!  Thanks again!

Comment: `def` defines a function, not a variable.